# input.value=<variable> returning static value [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, variables, while-loop, output

I'm very new to this, and have recently made a very primitive program that will calculate x^y for integer values of x and y. The script

```
var total = 1;
var power = 0;
var x = 4;
var y = 2;
while(power<=(y-1))
{power+=1;
 total*=(x);}
print(total);
```

works in a javascript console, but when I try to make a simple HTML file

```
<html>
<title>Score Verifier</title>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function calculate()
{
var x=document.getElementById('x');
var y=document.getElementById('y');
var result=document.getElementById('result');
var total = 1;
var power = 0;
while(power<=(y-1))
{
power+=1;
 total*=(x+(power-power));}
result.value=total
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Calculate x^y<br />
Enter x: <input id="x" type="text" /><br />
Enter y: <input id="y" type="text" /><br />
<input id="calc" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" /><br />
Result: <input id="result" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

I always get a "1" in the result input. How do I make it give the total from the while loop?

Comment: You forget to take value of the object. `document.getElementById('y')` => `document.getElementById('y').value`

Answer (score 2):

You always get 1 (the initial value), because your code never enters into `while` loop. Your `x` and `y` are of type `object`, thats why `y - 1` will return `NaN` (not-a-number) and thats why `power<=(y-1)` will always be `false`.

You should get *the value* of input element (which will be `string`) and then convert it to integer:

```
var x=parseInt(document.getElementById('x').value);
var y=parseInt(document.getElementById('y').value);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/73xnS/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value by `document.getElementById('x');` which is wrong but should be something like

```
var x=parseInt(document.getElementById('x').value, 10);
//-------------------------------------Use----^
```

*OR*

```
var x = +document.getElementById('x').value;
//------^---this operator converts string to number
```

*Instead of*

```
var x=document.getElementById('x');
```

You can use the `parseInt()` function to convert the string to number.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rY94d/)

Comment: Because of zero explanation, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This always returns that DOM object

```
var x=document.getElementById('x');
var y=document.getElementById('y');
var result=document.getElementById('result');
```

You can use

```
document.getElementById('elementid').value;
```